# Divisibility of sum of exponents

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Consider the sequence

$$r, \ ra, \ ra^2, \ ra^3, ... \ , ra^n  \mod M  $$

such that:

$$ ra^{n+1} \equiv  r   \mod M$$

and $a  \ne 1$ and $a,r$ are both coprime to $M$

Is it always true then that:

$$ r + ra + \ ra^2 + \ ra^3 ... + \ ra^n \equiv 0 \mod M$$

Consider the case of $M = 7$ just to get a better feel for the problem:

For $ r = 2 \ a = 3 $

$$ 2 + 2*3 + 2*3^2 ... 2*3^5 = 2 \frac{1 - 3^6}{1 -3} \equiv 0  \mod 7  $$

We can also look at

$r = 2 \ a = 4 $

$$ 2 + 2*2 + 2*4  \equiv 2 + 4 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 7 $$

Why does this appear to be the case? Is there counter-example

Comment: Try something with $\gcd(a-1,M) > 1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Your example of $M = 7$ does not make sense unless you mean $ra^{n+1} \equiv r$. Then, since $\gcd(M,r) = 1$, we have $a^{n+1} \equiv 1 \pmod M$. You also probably mean $a$ is not $\equiv 1$.

Since $a$ is not $\equiv 1$, the sum is equal to $r \cdot \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1} \equiv 0 \pmod M$.

Comment: Ah I see: the $a^{n+1} - 1 \equiv 0 \mod M$ but still how do I know for fact that $\frac{1}{a-1}$ is well defined $\mod M$ ?

Comment: It need not be, and then the argument breaks down, and the result need not hold.

Comment: That is a very legitimate question. Sorry, I had not thought about that. If $\gcd(a-1, M) = 1$, then $\frac{1}{a-1}$ can be treated as the modular inverse of $a-1$ but otherwise...

Comment: Say $M=8$, $r=1$, $a=3$.

Comment: Also, are we picking the minimal $n$ such that $a^{n+1} \equiv 1$? If thats the case, then we can prove that $(1,a, \cdots, a^n)$ cycle over all resides besides $0 \pmod M$. So the sum will be $r \cdot \frac{(M-1)M}2$. If $M$ is even (and $r$ is not), it is easy to see that the observation does not necessarily hold. EDIT: The above is also not necessarily true. It is only true if $n$ is large enough so disregard this.